# php replacing string error

Tags: php, post

I am trying to delete a string from a string, but the result of strstr is not finding the string. I will try to be as clear as I can here....

The problem is strpos() is not finding $deletTabHTML. I have alerted it in ajax and it is exactly the same as a line in the commonHTML, but obviously it isn't for some reason I cannot figure out. I am assuming I am missing something 'invisible'? My script works if I hardcode the html to be deleted, so the overall script works.

here is the php:

```
$commonHTML = file_get_contents($url);
if (!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'deleteTab') {
    $deletTabHTML = trim($_POST['theHTM']);
    if(strpos($commonHTML, $deletTabHTML) !== false) {
        $is_deleted="deleted";
    }else{
        $is_deleted="NOT deleted, ERROR:".$deletTabHTML;
    }
    echo '{"is_deleted":"' . $is_deleted . '"}';
    return;
}
```

MORE INFO: 
jQuery is getting an element from the dom and sending it to a php script which is opening a file and deleting the element:

```
<li id="contact"><a href="#contact" rel="ajax">Contact</a></li>
```

The data returned to ajax is:

```
<li id="contact"><a href="#contact" rel="ajax">Contact</a></li>
```

but for some reason it is not finding it. Thos were copied and pasted from the actual file and a javascript alert. They look exactly the same.

I hope that is enough info.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($commonHTML);` and `var_dump($deletTabHTML);`

Comment: Is the trim function correctly defined ? should it be str_replace instead?

Comment: Did you mean to drop an L off of `$_POST['theHTM']`?  Might want to use `stripos` in case they have different capitalization.  On a final note, your code does no text replacement.  Is that intentional?

Comment: have you tried giving different string on $_POST['theHTM']? or are you trying with the same string?

Comment: Agree with GigaWatt... check that you are calling the correct POST variables. Also, strpos is case sensitive, not sure if this would be a problem, but if so use stripos instead.

Comment: The missing L is intentional. And as of right now, there is no replacement until it can find the thing to replace.

Comment: karthik- I did actually try the actual string from the commonHTML file and it worked. The $_POST['theHTM'] is an element sent by an ajax post function, in which it got it from common html.

Comment: I did kind of do a dump, I returned the $_POST['theHTM'] to the ajax call that sent it and it looks exactly correct.

Comment: I found the answer, in part thanks to Briedis. Since this was executed from an ajax call I couldn't var_dump, but I did dump the contents to files and compared them, the POST['theHTM'] had slashes added to it and the ajax must have automagically removed them, so I didn't see them. So the answer is to use

$deletTabHTML = stripslashes($_POST['theHTM']);

Thank you to everyone that lead me to this conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strpos` is case sensitive

Try

```
stripos()
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from attempting to make the text search case insensitive, you also might want to make sure that it contains no unicode characters by using [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) on it first.

Lastly, it couldn't hurt to do some sanity checks on `$_POST['theHTM']` before attempting to use it.  (It looks like it's missing an L at the end, but it's also worth using isset() to verify that it actually exists.)

Comment: Nope, thank you for the try though. There are some checks in now but I have condensed this code so hopefully it was easier to read. I am 100% sure it exists, I have alerted it out in the ajax page.